# gcutil addinstance no longer returns IP address of instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

I just upgraded to gcutil 1.10.0 and I notice that the table that's returned upon completion of addinstance no longer contains the IP address of the instance. I extract that address to use in other scripts so I noticed it was gone immediately.

Looking at gcutil commands, it looks like "listaddresses" should give me the information I'm looking for; however, it returns no entries, just a table header. (The instance is running when I try this.)

So I guess if we're not going to produce the IP address in the output of addinstance anymore, I could use help figuring out how to get the address by a command-line query.

John K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the address for the instance by using:

gcutil listinstances --columns=all

Alternatively, you can just specify the columns you want.  You can get the list of valid columns using:

gcutil help listinstances

Answer (score 2):

A future release will add this back by default.  We removed columns to make it fit on a more typical terminal but perhaps went too far.

In the meantime, you can run:

```
gcutil listinstances --columns=name,zone,external-ip,status
```

Sorry for the inconvenience!